# can't use css with display:none & display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a option of 2 choices..when the user picks one I am bring up questions for them. I am ok with that part and it works, but when I do anything to the css it stops working. is am using display:none & display:block I have attached a fiddle below, so i can keep this kind of short.

```
<select>
<option value=>owner</option>
<option value=>non-owner</option>
</select>

.list { display:none; }
.list.active { 
display:block
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/embedded/result/

Comment: have you tried jQuery's functions for .hide and .show, or .toggle?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand your problem either...you can modify the css, just don't delete the display: http://jsfiddle.net/CcVsz/1/

Comment: Seems to be working for me, if it's supposed to do what I think it's supposed to do ?

Comment: Give us an example of you changing the css to show us how it has stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but the symptoms that I could glean indicate to me that you aren't adding a semi-colon after display: block, before adding any other CSS.  You need this:

```
.list { display: none; }
.list.active { 
    display: block; 

    /* Any other CSS after this should work fine.
       For example */
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
}
```

If that's not the problem, then please clarify what exactly you change that causes it to stop working.

Comment: I was going to add a fiddle of it not working lol...bad when you have problems that are not ever problems.

Comment: super sorry guys i was missing a ; and when i re did it in the fiddle i must have fixed it. sorry about that it was i problem i had yesterday right before sleep after a long day, and when i got up i got right back to it.

Comment: @philly - don't forget to accept this answer, since it seems to have answered your question.